# C# async: Disposing blocked thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Is there any way to dispose executing async function? I know, there is something called CancellationToken, but it is useful only if the function exection isn't blocked.

I've read it's a bad practice to try abort the thread because the program might get into broken state. But to fix my issue it's necessarily to abort the blocked execution (I put breath summary of the issue I'm facing bellow). So to fix the issue I've used a solution using Thread but I'd like to use async function instead.

**So my question is:** *How can I get rid of an async function its execution is being blocked?*

*Issue summary:*

- I develop UI automation tests
- There is a propertygrid property that is supposed to be set
- When a value is set (by using ValuePattern) to the property and then a dialog occurs then the execution get blocked
- Execution is blocked for an infinite time and continue only after the dialog is confirmed manually

*Current solution:*

- I have to run setting property value in a different thread
- Then I wait for a specific time or until the thread is completed
- If the thread is not completed in given time I abort the thread
- If the blocking dialog was expected it's confirmed and the test continues otherwise a failure is evaluated

Comment: What does "being blocked" mean? If it means the code hangs, then you're out of luck. All the warnings about not aborting threads kick in and you shouldn't abort the thread. If you *have* to abort the thread, then do what is normally suggested. Isolate the broken code into its own process so that you can kill the process, not just a single thread. This is still not entirely OK, but at least it is safer than having a broken process trying to hobble through.

Comment: As for, how can you terminate the thread a task is running on? You can't out of the box, you don't have this information. You will have to make sure the task reports which thread it is on right before it gets to the "could be hanging" part.

Comment: Asynchronous methods in most cases [don't run on threads](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), so there is nothing to abort. A truly asynchronous method is either cancelable, or impossible to cancel.

Comment: You can't "dispose" a function anyway, for two reasons. C# has methods, not functions - this is more a terminology hair to split. Secondly, a method in .net is not something you can allocate or garbage collect.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So based on your comments two questions poped in my mind: 1. What's the motivation to run the broken code in a proccess instead of running it in a thread? 2. How to make task to report which thread it was right before it got in the "could be hanging" part?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias So async methods are not designed to be aborted. The only way how to interrupt execution of an async method is to use CancellationToken. Am I right?

Comment: Olafvolafka yeap, exactly.

Comment: No, it's not "the only method", you can use whatever method you want, but CancellationToken is the method supplied to you by the class library that is supported throughout.

Comment: The reason for running it in a separate process is that if you terminate a thread and leave the process running you might have all sorts of problems *with that process*. Things like corrupt internal data structures, memory or other type of resource leaks, inconsistent runtime state, etc. The .NET runtime has gotten better over the years at handling some of the issues more gracefully, but it still isn't recommended to terminate a thread. Killing a whole process removes a lot of those issues because if the process becomes corrupt when you terminate the thread, it's being terminated as well.